# can't debug application in android studio

Tags: android, adb, television

the ADB file was erased by avast antivirus. I Downloaded platform-tools from official android site  extract it and paste it in the SDK folder
now i can see emulators but i have problems with debugging

the error message is

```
3:35 PM 'cmd package install-create -r -t  -S 11679368' returns error 'Unknown failure: cmd: Can't find service: package'

3:35 PM Session 'app': Install failed.
                Installation failed
                Rerun
```

i'm using android studio 3.4.1

Comment: in all honesty, you might be better off just downloading and installing android studio again

Comment: Thanks, you've solved the problem